# Python printing loop of three in a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I wrote a simple script in python to return the Official name of a website, any aliases, and all their IP addresses. I used gethostbyname_ex() for this. I am aware it is limited to only displaying ipv4 addresses as well.

Click below to see the code

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uKUd.png)

However, it seems to loop three times. I am not sure why. I assume it is because the tuple has three elements in it? I know I am missing something probably small to get it to work, but I tried everything I could think of. I get the results below.

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wrlr.png)

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Put the code in the question, not behind a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.gethostbyname_ex` returns a tuple of length three containing name, aliases and addresses, you don't have to iterate to access its values, you can simply do:

```
name, aliases, addresses = socket.gethostbyname_ex('www.google.com')
print('Official Name:', name)
print('Aliases:', aliases)
print('Addresses:', addresses)
```

Comment: I did try to use item instead of list before posting and I got the same error I just got trying this code. The errors are "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File line 9, in <module>
    print('Official Name:', item[0])" and " IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: I misunderstood initially, i have updated my answer, try that.